# How to implicitly cast templated constructor arguments?

Tags: c++, class, templates, constructor

I'm overloading the constructor of a templated class `A` with different input types, for both scalar and container-type arguments:

```
template<typename T>
class A {
public:
    A();
    A(T&& _val) { printf("non-template constructor\n");} ;
    template<typename iT> A(const iT& _cont) { printf("template constructor\n");};

};


int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {


    A<float> foo1(0.9);                     //template constructor
    A<float> foo2((float)0.9);              //no-template constructor 
    A<float> foo3(std::vector<int>(5,8));   //template constructor


    return 0;
}
```

However, is there a way to call force the non-template constructor on implicitly castable types e.g. passing a `double` to constructor `A<float>()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can add a SFINAE-constraint to your constructor template:

```
template<typename iT,
         std::enable_if_t<!std::is_convertible_v<iT&&, T>>* = nullptr>
A(const iT&) { printf("template constructor\n"); }
```

This has the effect of causing substitution failure for the deduced type `iT` when `iT&&` is convertible to `T`, which removes the constructor template from the overload set.

(You need to `#include <type_traits>` for the various library facilities used to express the constraint.)

Comment: `A<float> foo1(a);` where `a` is a lvalue of double doesn't work. Only failed in MSVC though.

Comment: Awesome. What would be the C++11 equivalent though?

Comment: @joaocandre, `typename std::enable_if<!std::is_convertible<iT&&, T>::value>::type*`.

Comment: @Evg that won't compile for me, the template constructor is not recognized as valid for the third instantiation.

Comment: @joaocandre try `typename std::enable_if<!std::is_convertible<iT&&, T>::value, void>::type*`. BTW, this answer is flawed. Deducing by `A(const iT& _cont)` will lost value category. For certain usage, you will be unable to know whether the argument can be converted to `T &&` or not.

Comment: Failing as well, with `couldn't deduce template parameter ‘<anonymous>’`

Comment: @joaocandre Can you try to reproduce the error in https://godbolt.org/ and share the link here?

Comment: IIRC `void*` is not a valid non-type template parameter.

Comment: @joaocandre, try this: `template<typename iT, typename = typename std::enable_if<!std::is_convertible<iT&&, T>::value>::type>`.