# Different member function definition according to compile-time condition

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, type-traits, overloading

As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53338196/2340002), I've been using

```
template <typename T,
          typename = typename enable_if<bool_verfier<T>()>::type> >
classMember(const T& arg);
```

As the function signature for several class members, where `bool_verifier<T>()` is a templated function that asserts that a particular class `T` fulfills certain requirements, with return type `constexpr bool`. This ensures a particular overload of `classMember(const T& arg)` is only used for particular argument types, but it is not possible to do this when there are multiple overloads with the same prototype/argument signature, because the compiler won't allow it:

```
// ...
template <typename T, typename = typename enable_if<bool_verfier<T>()>::type> >
classMember(const T& arg);
template <typename T,  typename = typename enable_if<!(bool_verfier<T>())>::type>>
classMember(const T& arg);
// ...
```

which causes the following compilation error:

```
 ‘template<class T, class> void myClass::classMember<T>(const T&)’
 cannot be overloaded with
‘template<class T, class> void std::myClass<T>::classMember(const T&)’
```

If I need `classMember` to have different definitions according to whether or not `bool_verifier<T>()` returns true, what would be the correct syntax/member declaration? Alternatively, is there a way to call `bool_verifier<T>` from an `#if` precompiler conditional statement?

Comment: *"because the compiler won't allow it"*. As always, provide an [MCVE] and the error message...

Comment: @VittorioRomeo presumably because enable if was put as a default value, which is not part of the signature, leading to redefinition

Comment: Do you have C++17?

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki: sure, but the OP needs to put that in the question. We shouldn't have to do guesswork

Comment: @VittorioRomeo The compiler won't allow precisely because no compiler will accept function overloads with the same prototype. I've edited the question.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher No, I'm doing this with C++11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Alternatively, is there a way to call `bool_verifier<T>` from an `#if` precompiler conditional statement?

Nope. The preprocessor runs before anything else, and doesn't have knowledge of C++ at all.

---

You probably need to disambiguate between the two overloads with an extra template parameter (or by changing where `enable_if` appears), as default template parameter values are not part of the signature. The following works for me:

```
struct foo
{
     template <typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t<bool_verifier<T>{}>> 
     void a();

     template <typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t<!bool_verifier<T>{}>, typename = void> 
     void a();
};
```

[**live godbolt.org link**](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/T9HWSW)

Comment: While this seems to work regarding overload/template resolution, if I call `arg.dim()` in the first overload when `arg` is of type `std::vector<int>`, it will result in a compilation error `has no member named dim()`, despite in such a case the second overload would be used, as `bool_verifier` would return `false`.

Comment: Also, that seems to be a separate issue. Please mark this as resolved, and post a new question with a proper MCVE + compiler error.